# Vue multiple this.function() is not working

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

This is mine handleMove function which is basically working like

```
<div class="container" @mousemove="handleMove"></div>
```

I want to pass Multiple function where i have bold in the code the problem is that when i am doing this.moveSelectedNode(diffX,diffY) the other 
this.moveSelectedDecision is not working

The issue is that one Nodes are going in this.moveSelectedDecision and vice versa for the decisions

when i Comment the One this the other this is working Fine

When i comment one this.moveSelectedNode or this.moveSelectedDecision the other one is working all fine

```
 handleMove(e) {
          if (this.action.linking) {
            [this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y] = getMousePosition(this.$el, e);
            [this.draggingLink.mx, this.draggingLink.my] = [this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y];
          }
          if (this.action.dragging) {
            this.mouse.x = e.pageX || e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft
            this.mouse.y = e.pageY || e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop
            let diffX = this.mouse.x - this.mouse.lastX;
            let diffY = this.mouse.y - this.mouse.lastY;

            this.mouse.lastX = this.mouse.x;
            this.mouse.lastY = this.mouse.y;
            this.moveSelectedNode(diffX, diffY);
            **this.moveSelectedDecision(diffX,diffY);**
            console.log('I am here');
          }
          if (this.action.scrolling) {
            [this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y] = getMousePosition(this.$el, e);
            let diffX = this.mouse.x - this.mouse.lastX;
            let diffY = this.mouse.y - this.mouse.lastY;

            this.mouse.lastX = this.mouse.x;
            this.mouse.lastY = this.mouse.y;

            this.scene.centerX += diffX;
            this.scene.centerY += diffY;

            // this.hasDragged = true
          }
        },
```

These are mine moveSelectedNode and moveSelectedDecision function which i am passing up in handleMove

```
moveSelectedNode(dx, dy) {
      let index = this.scene.nodes.findIndex((item) => {
        return item.id === this.action.dragging
      })
      let left = this.scene.nodes[index].x + dx / this.scene.scale;
      let top = this.scene.nodes[index].y + dy / this.scene.scale;
      this.$set(this.scene.nodes, index, Object.assign(this.scene.nodes[index], {
        x: left,
        y: top,
      }));
    },
     moveSelectedDecision(dx, dy) {
      let index = this.scene.decisions.findIndex((item) => {
        return item.id === this.action.dragging
      })
      let left = this.scene.decisions[index].x + dx / this.scene.scale;
      let top = this.scene.decisions[index].y + dy / this.scene.scale;
      this.$set(this.scene.decisions, index, Object.assign(this.scene.decisions[index], {
        x: left,
        y: top,
      }));
    },
```

Comment: so it seems that the problem may be with `moveSelectedNode` and/or `moveSelectedDecision`. Unfortunately without knowing what these functions do, or without knowing what _not working_ means, it's hard to make any suggestions.

Comment: Daniel i am posting these functions in mine Question please check again @Daniel